# Check how many arguments a method has on Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I have multiple classes that extends an abstract class A.

The abstract class has the following two methods:

```
public abstract int methodOne (int n);
public abstract int methodTwo (int n);
```

One of the classes, class B, that extends the class A overloads one of the methods for instance:

```
public int methodOne (int n) {
    return n * 2;
}

public int methodOne (int n, int k) {
    return n * k;
}
```

Now we are working with an instance of the class B, is there a way to check if the method `methodOne` has been overloaded and if so make a condition.

```
A ourTest = new B();
```

If `methodOne` has two arguments then use the method with two arguments, otherwise use the `methodOne` with one argument.

Comment: `Java` != `JavaScript`. Could you explain what do you want to achive? It is possible, but I think you do wrong what you do.

Comment: Can u adapt also the class A?

Comment: This question makes no sense, first `methodOne (int n)` is declared `abstract` so it must be implemented (overriden), secondly since you declare `ourTest` to be of type `A` you cannot call `methodOne (int n, int k)` since it is specific for `B`

Comment: Once an instance of `B` is assigned to a variable of type `A` (like `ourTest`), you can't access the method with the two arguments anymore because it's not declared in `A`. You'd need to use reflection or cast it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to inspect what methods `B` declares. Note there are 2 flavors:

```
B.getClass().getMethods()
```

Will give you an array of `Method` objects representing all of the public methods of the class, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.

You can also call

```
B.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()
```

Will give you an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, **but excluding inherited methods**.

Not that in your case, class `A` doesn't have a 2 argument form of `methodOne` so it technically cannot be inherited or overridden in `B`.

So, you could call `getDeclaredMethods()` and loop over the array of `Method` objects to see if `B` has a 2 argument form of `methodOne`.

This works **even if you declared an object of type A but instantiate it with `new B()`**.

The following sample code shows it in action:

```
public abstract class A {
   public abstract int methodOne (int n);
   public abstract int methodTwo (int n);
}

public class B extends A {
   @Override
   public int methodOne(int n) {
      return n;
   }

   public int methodOne(int n, int k) {
      return n + k;
   }

   @Override
   public int methodTwo(int n) {
      return n * 2;
   }
}

// test it out (note that this can throw several different exceptions
// so you'll have to handle them..I left that out to keep the code
// concise.

A a = new B();
Method[] methods = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

for(Method m : methods) {
    System.out.println(m.toGenericString());
    if(m.getName().equals("methodOne") && m.getParameterCount() == 2) {
        int result = (int)m.invoke(a, 3, 2);
        System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    }
}
```

This will print the following:

```
public int B.methodTwo(int)
public int B.methodOne(int,int)
Result = 5
public int B.methodOne(int)
```

Comment: The object to test is declared as `A` so you can't invoke the method with two parameters.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Calling `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` will return the overloaded `methodOne` in this case, and you can invoke it dynamically. See the sample code I added to the answer.

Comment: Ok that is interesting that you can invoke a method this way that can't be invoked in a normal way but I am not sure when this would ever be a good solution.

Comment: Agree, it has to be done via reflection but it's possible. Most DI/IoC frameworks *have* to use reflection to do their job so it's more common than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

You have no same method with one or two arguments. Both methods are different although have the same name (methodOne). If you want to find how many arguments a method has, or if it has been overloaded, there is Java Reflection API available. But you are trying to do seems to make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> If `methodOne` has two arguments then use the method with two arguments, otherwise use the `methodOne` with one argument.

No, you cannot do that, because Java is statically typed.

Since `A` defines only the one-argument version of `methodOne`, that is all you'll ever have for code that uses variables of type `A`.

Any method added to subclasses are not visible in plain Java code for variables of type `A`. You can only call such "extra" methods by either casting to the subclass in question, or by using reflection.